# Windows 10 Anniversary Update arrival date

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1607

I know that the release date was on August 2. I also know that I can update manually. But what I'm wondering is why haven't I received the update automatically yet, and when is it going to happen.

Also, how does Microsoft decide when to ship the update to which customers? Is it random, or does it depend on my country, or perhaps some other parameters?

Comment: Have you checked windows update?  What build are you currently on?  What version of windows 10 do you have (pro, home, etc)?

Comment: @TimmyJim Yes, I've checked Windows Update - it sometimes installs minor updates, such as Defender definitions, but not the Anniversary Update. Windows 10 Pro, Version 10.0.10586.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with the release of Windows 10, the Anniversary update does not get distributed to everyone on the release date.

Microsoft will make it available to everyone over the coming weeks.  It will be rolled out to models of machines that have been tested first, then newer machines in general, then on to older machines, etc.

You can download and manually install it if you want.

Comment: Thanks. "It will be rolled out to models of machines that have been tested first" - is it a documented behavior?

Answer (score 2):

It might even take weeks for the feature update (v1607) to appear in WU. If you don't want to wait, you can use the [upgrade assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history) to install it right away.

Another option would be to use the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10) to create a installation media (or) the ISO itself, and do an in-place upgrade by mounting the ISO and running `Setup.exe`.