# How to upgrade windows 10 os build version to 14393.0 or later?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10-upgrade

I want to install the Ubuntu sybsystem on windows 10. But, I found that the os build version required is `14393.0` while I have the build `10586` here what I get when I go `settings > system > about`

[image]

for that,the Linux subsytem is not available for installation on my system.

> I have installed the updates before. As a result the version was updated to 1511 but the OS Build remained as it is

**the question:**

Is their any way to upgrade the OS Build to a higher version that support installing Linux subsystem without reinstalling windows ?

Comment: Related: [How to install Windows 10 Anniversary Update on Windows 10 Enterprise edition](http://superuser.com/questions/1110580/how-to-install-windows-10-anniversary-update-on-windows-10-enterprise-edition). Related: [Where can I get a clean ISO of the Windows 10 Anniversary update (Build 14393)?](http://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-the-windows-10-anniversary-update-build-14393)

Comment: Related: [Windows 10 Anniversary Update arrival date](http://superuser.com/questions/1113483/windows-10-anniversary-update-arrival-date/1113498#1113498)

Comment: thanks a lot @Ramhound. so what I understand is that solution is to download a clean ISO and install it. Is there any risk that I loose my files or not ?

Comment: The upgrade procedure you just described end result, is the exact same result, if you install the feature update through Windows Update.